# Stopping a Timer With Virtual Keys

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, virtual, key

I've created a basic window which handles virtual keys. The case `VK_UP` initializes a timer which is counting from 9 backwards. The timer can be stopped if either 0 is reached or `VK_DOWN` is pressed. The problem is, when I initialize the timer with `VK_UP` the program stops until the timer has reached 0. How can I interrupt( stop ) the timer with `VK_DOWN`?

As always, I've tried search but to no avail.

EDIT: Here's the window procedure:

```
unsigned Seconds( 9 );
case WM_KEYDOWN:
     {
         switch( wParam )
         {
             case VK_UP:
                  {
                      while( Seconds > 0 )
                      {
                          wait( 1 );
                          Seconds--;
                      }
                  }
                  break;
         }
         break;
     }
```

Here's the `wait( )` method I used above:

```
void wait( unsigned TotalSeconds )
{
    clock_t Wait( clock( ) + ( TotalSeconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ) );
    while( clock( ) < Wait )
    {
        Sleep( 1 );
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If this is windows, please add windows or winapi tag

Comment: Please show the code where you start the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real timer, not a counting loop.  Review [SetTimer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Understanding the event driven programming model for Windows is pretty important, it is well covered by any book about Windows programming, like Petzold's.